# Check if WordPress theme supports sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called `movies` which has template for single post type page. I am creating the single page template using the below filter.

```
add_filter('single_template', 'set_single_movie_template', 10, 1);
function set_single_movie_template($single_template){
    global $post;
    if ('movies' === $post->post_type) {
        $single_template = MOVIE_CPT_TEMPLATES.'/single-movie.php';
    }
    return $single_template;
}
```

And this is my post type single page template

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header();

while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    get_movie_template_part( 'content', 'single-movie' );
endwhile; // end of the loop.

do_action( 'movies_sidebar' );

get_footer();
```

The issue is I am calling the theme sidebar in the `movies_sidebar` action hook as shown below.

```
add_action('movie_sidebar', 'get_sidebar_template');
function get_sidebar_template(){
    get_movie_template('global/sidebar.php');
}
```

This calls a template file in my plugin in a folder called global. The above said template file `sidebar.php` contains the following.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_sidebar();
```

**ERROR**

This works fine in many themes. But in Twenty Twenty One and Twenty Twenty themes (Themes with no sidebar), I am getting an error

> Deprecated: Theme without sidebar.php is deprecated since version
> 3.0.0 with no alternative available. Please include a sidebar.php template in your theme

I have been stuck for the past full day trying to solve this. As far as I have checked, the above said themes don't have a sidebar.php file in theme and hence the error.

**Current Solution**

I have made a custom condition with theme names such that `get_sidebar()` is called only when the active theme is in the array of theme names which supports sidebar. Still I have to add theme names to the list, when I encounter a theme that doesn't support sidebar.

Is there any solution available for this problem ?

Comment: @Ruvee This is not helpful. `is_active_sidebar` requires a parameter, the name of the sidebar. I tried using `primary` as parameter. Still the logic is not working. What I need is something to check if `get_sidebar` can be used for this theme or not

Answer (score -1):

### Statement

This is not an error, but a deprecated message.

There are WordPress themes that do not include the `sidebar.php` template file, which is deprecated as the message says, but this is not a problem because if it is not found in the theme, it will load `/wp-includes/theme-compat/sidebar.php` file.

So this is not a problem that needs to be solved or can be solved because it is not an error, it is not an unresolved problem.

This message is included in the WordPress core `/wp-includes/theme-compat/sidebar.php` fallback file for backward compatibility. So that's the solution, they made the solution, they just added a deprecated message to it.

Since there is a fallback solution, you do not need to check that `sidebar.php` exists in the theme.

### Solution

This deprecated message is only visible if `WP_DEBUG` is enabled. So this message will not be visible on a production website where `WP_DEBUG` is disabled in `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

But there are other ways to disable this deprecated file message:

```
add_action( 'deprecated_file_trigger_error', '__return_false' );
```

But don’t use this `add_action` solution if you’re developing a product (like a WordPress plugin that other users use). Use this only for your own website if you want to disable the message.

But as I wrote, this is not a problem that you have to solve.

Comment: This is a problem for me or many. The fallback message cannot be considered as a solution. This message can only be considered as warning. `get_sidebar` should return false or something like that if the theme doesn't have sidebar.php. Or atleast there should be a function to check if the theme has a sidebar.php file. Since this post type can be used with any themes, we cannot presume whether the theme will have a sidebar or not.

Comment: Also turning of debug mode is not a solution, the issue still exists but will be hidden from displaying.

Comment: @melvin Deprecated is not an issue and is handled in the WordPress core anyway. Like I said, you don’t have to solve a non-existent problem because it’s not a problem, it's not an issue. But even if you think of it as an issue for some reason, it’s still a theme issue that doesn’t need to be handled in a plugin.

It is completely pointless to write a function for this to see if "sidebar exists" as there is no possibility that the sidebar will not work or not exists because there is a WordPress core fallback file for it.

Comment: Deprecated is not an issue. But it can be an issue when the plugin needs some features of a common theme. Every user requires the plugin to be compatible with the theme. A plugin cannot presume whether the theme has a sidebar or not. So the plugin should handle both cases and there need to be some sort of functionality for checking whether sidebar is supported. Most of the themes support a sidebar, So I understand WordPress handled it this way, but i would be better if they have handled it some other way